# My New Route Is Not Working

Tags: magento-1.9, module, magento-1, controllers

I want to create new route, **ex:brand**

I tried to access `www.myPage.com/brand` and `www.myPage.com/index.php/brand`

But it just shows 404 page not found after I create this scripts bellow.

**This is my `IndexController.php` scripts :**

```
<?php

class MyWeb_Brand_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo 'Hello developer...';
    }

    public function sayHelloAction()
    {
        echo 'Hello one more time...';
    }
}
?>
```

**My `config.xml` scripts :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <MyWeb_Brand>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MyWeb_Brand>
    </modules>    
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <MyWeb_Brand_Route>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>MyWeb_Brand</module>
                    <frontName>brand</frontName>
                </args>
            </MyWeb_Brand_Route>
        </routers>
    </frontend>    
</config>
```

**And this my `app/etc/modules/myWeb_Brand.xml` file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <MyWeb_Brand>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </MyWeb_Brand>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: after did the changes whether you have removed cache session?

Comment: yes, I've removed my cache session but nothing's happen

Comment: please follow the link http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/ which is useful for the creating a module easily.

Comment: your link is actually a magic, THANK YOU NAGARAJU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Location of activation file is wrong here. It should be `app\etc\modules\MyWeb_Brand.xml` instead of `app/etc/module/myPage_Brand`.

Also please note **[Raphael's answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/158951/3535)** too. They are actually coding and concept standards, not a complete requirement.

Also make sure locations of following files are correct.

- Config File : `app\code\local\MyWeb\Brand\etc\config.xml`
- Controller  : `app\code\local\MyWeb\Brand\controllers\IndexController.php`

With these, your are good to go, I guess.

Please make sure, you remove all your caches after these changes applied.

Comment: I'm sorry my question has some typos. I've edited my question. please check again

Comment: please see edit in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `config.xml` file with below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyWeb_Brand>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MyWeb_Brand>
    </modules>    
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <brand>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>MyWeb_Brand</module>
                    <frontName>brand</frontName>
                </args>
            </brand>
        </routers>
    </frontend>    
</config>
```

In above file have one mistake you wrote **Nekindo_Brand** but module name is  **MyWeb_Brand**

Your module config filename is **MyWeb_Brand.xml** at **app/etc/modules/MyWeb_Brand.xml** instead of **myPage_Brand.xml**

Answer (score 1):

I reckon you need to update the router declaration part like this:

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <brand>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>MyWeb_Brand</module>
                <frontName>brand</frontName>
            </args>
        </brand>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

On top of that, the file under `app/etc/modules` should be renamed `MyWeb_Brand.xml`

Comment: I'm sorry my question has some typos. I've edited my question. please check again

Comment: @syahidahhumairoh even after editing your question, my answer still applies to your question. Please apply my changes

Answer (score 0):

Change your config XML router like this:-

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <brand>
            ......
        </brand>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```